# How to break a while loop when input is a particular string?

Tags: python

I need to stop adding up user inputs when one of them is the string "F".
So basically If my input is a int then : += result, if the same input variable is a string then I need to stop and add them together.

My code actually works and has the same inputs and outputs the exercise demands but I'm very unhappy with the way I resolve it.

This is my code:

```
import numbers
cat = int(input())


def norm(cat):
    res = 0
    for n in range(cat):
      x = int(input())
      res += x

    print(res)

def lon():
    res = 0
    while 2 > 1:
     try :
         y = int(input())
         if isinstance(y,int):
           res +=y
     except:
        print(res)
        break




if cat >= 0 :
    norm(cat)
else:
    lon()
```

It's actually breaking the while loop in a stupid way by checking if my variable is an int. (I need to make it stop by simply pressing F)
Is there any cleaner and shorter way to obtain the same outputs?

Example of the actual inputs-outputs I expect :

```
in:       out:16    (1 + 3 + 5 + 7)
4
1
3
5
7

in:       out:37     (1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 21)
-1
1
3
5
7
21
F
```

Comment: The first thing I'd say is stop saying "dumb" and "stupid". Drop that. You want to look into "scope" for functions and `global` would be a slippery slope even if it probably looks like a quick fix

Comment: Just save the input string into a variable `s` and then check `s == 'F'` to break out of the loop before converting `s` to an `int`. Using `try ... except` to break out of the loop is also fine IMO.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'm supposed to know nothing about functions or exceptions so the teacher expects from me a total different way of resolving this

Comment: You execute `y = int(input())` and in the next statement `if isinstance(y,int): res +=y`. If the first statement failed to convert the input to an int, an exception would have been thrown and you never would have fallen through to the second. So isn't that test for y being an int superfluous?

Comment: RIght, but Stack Overflow isn't a forum, it's supposed to be a repository of specific programming questions and answers. There is no need for self-deprecation - we've all been learners. Beyond that, see [this](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have written it a bit shorter:

```
result = 0

while True:
    line = input()
    try:
        result += int(line)
    except ValueError:
        break

print(result)
```

Notice:

- `import numbers` isn't needed. (I didn't even know that existed!)
- Instead of `2 > 1`, you can use `True`.
- You don't need to check `isinstance(..., int)` since `int()` enforces that.
- This runs until any non-integer string is reached.

---

If you want to specifically check for "F" *only*, it's a bit easier:

```
result = 0

while True:
    line = input()
    if line == "F":
        break
    result += int(line)

print(result)
```

Note that without using `try`, you'll crash the program if you input a non-integer, non-`"F"` string.